# Foreign Key Exists and I get MySQL Error: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

I have a simple query to update an intermediary table with some values from a VB NET application. I am only updating the BinLength Table and I get this Error when I try to do that:

```
MySQL Error: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails.
```

Which I know it is telling me that the related FK Id does not exist in
the Parent Table.

[Yet It does Exist!]. I queried it a few ways to sunshine and they are all there - each of the FK columns in my table has a respective ID in its foreign table!

So what kind of Error is this ..

I am also using InnoDb in all of my tables so I know it supports FK constraint.

Looking at the Data and the below provided information can someone point me in the right direction to solve this issue. I am banging my head on SO and MySQL to find an answer for 4 or 5 hours now and I am now where closer to having this resolved.

Below I have my Insert and Update Commands Provided by the command builder.
SQL FROM MYSQL COMMAND BUILDER

```
UPDATE `binlength` SET `binID` = @p1, `lengthID` = @p2, `recipeID` = @p3, `IsSelected` = @p4 WHERE ((`ID` = @p5) AND (`binID` = @p6) AND (`lengthID` = @p7) AND (`recipeID` = @p8) AND ((@p9 = 1 AND `IsSelected` IS NULL) OR (`IsSelected` = @p10)))

INSERT INTO `binlength` (`binID`, `lengthID`, `recipeID`, `IsSelected`) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4)
```

Below I have the 3 tables of interest - Id is the Primary key.
TableNameId represents a Foreign Key.

TABLE BINLENGTH Relevant Data.

```
# ID, binID, lengthID, recipeID, IsSelected
14,     1,  1,  1,  1
15,     1,  2,  1,  1
16,     1,  3,  1,  1
17,     1,  4,  1,  1
18,     1,  5,  1,  1
19,     1,  6,  1,  1
20,     1,  7,  1,  1
21,     1,  8,  1,  1
22,     1,  9,  1,  1
23,     1,  10, 1,  1
24,     1,  11, 1,  1
25,     1,  12, 1,  1
26,     1,  13, 1,  1
27,     1,  14, 1,  1
32,     8,  5,  1,  1
33,     8,  6,  1,  1
34,     8,  7,  1,  1
35,     2,  5,  1,  1
36,     25, 5,  1,  1
37,     28, 6,  1,  1
38,     20, 4,  1,  1
```

TABLE BINS  Relevant Data

```
# Id, Name, Filling_Width, Filling_Pc, Filling_Mbf, Mbf_Calculate, DimensionID, RecipeID, BinSetupID
1   BIN 1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1
2   BIN 2   99.99   99  99.99   99  12  1   2
3   BIN 3   0   0   0   0   1   1   3
4   BIN 4   0   0   0   0   1   1   4
5   BIN 5   0   0   0   0   12  1   5
6   BIN 6   12  12  12  12  9   1   6
7   BIN 7   0   0   0   0   2   1   7
8   BIN 8   12  12  12  12  2   1   8
9   BIN 9   0   0   0   0   17  1   9
10  BIN 10  0   0   0   0   1   1   10
11  BIN 11  0   0   0   0   24  1   11
12  BIN 12  0   0   0   0   9   1   12
13  BIN 13  0   0   0   0   1   1   13
14  BIN 14  0   0   0   0   1   1   14
15  BIN 15  0   0   0   0   1   1   15
16  BIN 16  0   0   0   0   1   1   16
17  BIN 17  0   0   0   0   1   1   17
18  BIN 18  0   0   0   0   1   1   18
19  BIN 19  0   0   0   0   1   1   19
20  BIN 20  0   0   0   0   1   1   20
21  BIN 21  0   0   0   0   1   1   21
22  BIN 22  0   0   0   0   1   1   22
23  BIN 23  0   0   0   0   1   1   23
24  BIN 24  0   0   0   0   1   1   24
25  BIN 25  0   0   0   0   1   1   25
26  BIN 26  0   0   0   0   1   1   26
27  BIN 27  0   0   0   0   1   1   27
28  BIN 28  0   0   0   0   1   1   28
29  BIN 29  0   0   0   0   1   1   29
30  BIN 30  0   0   0   0   1   1   30
```

TABLE LENGTHS  Relevant Data

```
# Id, Name, Min, Max, Nom, Actual_Real, Set_Default, Set_Enable, Visible, ndx

1   LENGTH1     0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   1   0   0   1
2   LENGTH2     0.100   0.200   0.000   0.000   0   1   0   2
3   LENGTH3     0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0   0   0   3
4   LENGTH4     0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0   0   0   4
5   LENGTH5     0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0   0   0   5
6   LENGTH6     0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0   0   0   6
7   LENGTH7     0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0   0   0   7
8   LENGTH8     0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0   0   0   8
9   LENGTH9     0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0   0   0   9
10  LENGTH10    0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0   0   0   10
11  LENGTH11    0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0   0   0   11
12  LENGTH12    0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0   0   0   12
13  LENGTH13    0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0   0   0   13
14  LENGTH14    0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0   0   0   14
15  LENGTH15    0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0   0   0   15
16  LENGTH16    0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0   0   0   16
17  LENGTH17    0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0   0   0   17
18  LENGTH18    0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0   0   0   18
19  LENGTH19    0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0   0   0   19
20  LENGTH20    0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0   0   0   20
```

Values that I am trying to Insert with the MySQL DataAdapter:

```
Row, ID, binID, lengthID, recipeID, IsSelected

0, 39, 6, 4, 1, 1

1, 40, 6, 6, 1, 1
```

I ran this SQL code against my tables to try to determine what was wrong.

```
SELECT DISTINCT BLength.ID 
FROM binlength As BLength LEFT JOIN bins As bay 
ON BLength.BinId=bay.id 
WHERE bay.id IS NULL;
```

SQL TABLE DEFINITIONS

```
CREATE TABLE `binlength` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `binID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'References the Bin.ID column of Table Bins',
  `lengthID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'References the Length.ID column of Table Lengths',
  `recipeID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'References the Recipe.ID column of Recipe Table.',
  `IsSelected` int(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Length is enabled for the selected bin.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID`),
  KEY `FK_BINID_BINID_idx` (`binID`),
  KEY `FK_LENID_LENID_idx` (`lengthID`),
  KEY `NDX_RecipeID` (`recipeID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_BINID_BINID` FOREIGN KEY (`binID`) REFERENCES `bins` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_LENID_LENID` FOREIGN KEY (`lengthID`) REFERENCES `lengths` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=44 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Intermediary Table [aka Associative Table] for bins and length';



CREATE TABLE `bins` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'BIN UNDEFINED',
  `Filling_Width` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Filling_Pc` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Filling_Mbf` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Mbf_Calculate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DimensionID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RecipeID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `BinSetupID` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Id_UNIQUE` (`Id`),
  KEY `FK_RecipeID_BINS_idx` (`RecipeID`),
  KEY `FK_BinRecipeID_Recipe_ID_idx` (`RecipeID`),
  KEY `BinSetUpID_ndx` (`BinSetupID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_BinRecipeID_Recipe_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`RecipeID`) REFERENCES `recipe` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1433 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `lengths` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(82) DEFAULT '""',
  `Min` decimal(11,3) DEFAULT '0.000',
  `Max` decimal(11,3) DEFAULT '0.000',
  `Nom` decimal(11,3) DEFAULT '0.000',
  `Actual_Real` decimal(11,3) DEFAULT '0.000',
  `Set_Default` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `Set_Enable` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `Visible` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `ndx` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `recipe` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'UnAssigned',
  `IsDefault` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Name_UNIQUE` (`Name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Id_UNIQUE` (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**EDIT**

In My VB Code  I load the data in from the MySql table closing the connection and the dataadapter is disposed - I make changes to the VB datatable. I then call the SaveDataTable() Method.

My Relevant VB Code is as Follows  : 
MySQLConector version is 6.98

```
Private Sub AddRows()
datasTable = Load_Table("Select * From Where RecipeID= 1")

' For the added rows
                        Dim drow As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
' Iam not setting the Id field in my code - I do not need to the addrow method magically adds it - based on MissingSchemaAction addwithkey
                        drow("Id") = 41 ' This is the next sequence number - it was grabbed from the load. 
                        drow("binID") = 13
                        drow("lengthId") = 1
                        drow("recipeID") = 1
                        drow("IsSelected") = 1
                        drow.EndEdit()
                        dt.Rows.Add(drow)


End Sub
```

ORIGINAL Load

```
Private Function Load_Table(query As String) As DataTable

    Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable

    Using Conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(DatabaseConnection)

        Using Comm As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, Conn)

            Comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text

            Using SDA As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(Comm)

                Try

                    Conn.Open()

                    SDA.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey

                    SDA.Fill(table)

                Catch sqlError As MySqlException

                    Dim exErr As String = String.Format("{0}: {1}", sqlError.Number, sqlError.Message)
                    MessageBox.Show(exErr, "Error While Loading Table", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

                Catch ex As Exception

                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error While Loading Table", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

                Finally

                    Conn.Close()

                End Try

            End Using

        End Using

    End Using

    Return table

End Function
```

SAVE DATA

```
Private Sub SaveDataTable(datasTable As DataTable, query As String)

        Using con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(DatabaseConnection)

            Using comm As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, con)

                comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text

                Using mySDA As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(comm)

                    Try

                        con.Open()

                        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable

            ' tried both with and with out this MissingSchemaAction  
                     '  mySDA.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey

                        mySDA.Fill(dt)

            ' Tried Both of these ..

                        dt.Merge(datasTable, True)

                     '   dt.Merge(datasTable, False)

                        Dim cmdBuild As MySqlCommandBuilder = New MySqlCommandBuilder(mySDA)

            ' Tried Building my own commands as well - same results.

            cmdBuild.GetInsertCommand()
                        cmdBuild.GetUpdateCommand()
                        cmdBuild.GetDeleteCommand()

                       mySDA.Update(dt)


                    Catch sqlError As MySqlException

                        Dim exErr As String = String.Format("MySQL Error: {0}: {1}", sqlError.Number, sqlError.Message)
                        MessageBox.Show(exErr, "Error While Saving Table", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

                    Catch concurrencyError As DBConcurrencyException

                        MessageBox.Show(concurrencyError.Message.ToString(), "Error While Saving Table", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

                    Catch ex As Exception

                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error While Saving Table", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

                    Finally

                        con.Close()

                    End Try

                End Using

            End Using

        End Using

End Sub
```

In MySqlException I get 
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydatabase`.`binlength`, CONSTRAINT `FK_BINID_BINID` FOREIGN KEY (`binID`) REFERENCES `bins` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

When I build my own query where I include the primary key with the values - I get binId can not be null - yet it is not null!

If I massage the thing and set the added rows to modified the SQL Adapter does not give an error but it does not upddate the database either.

If they are in an unchanged state - of course nothing happens and I do not get an error either.

Pictures Added

[image: Bins]
[image: BinLengthRows]
[image: Lengths]

Comment: You forgot the most critical part, the actual table definitions. PICTURES of the tables/data are pretty, but basically useless. you need to show the field and FK definitions.

Comment: @MarcB I posted the Create Table Statements - should show all that is needed.

Comment: You're using variables in your updates/insert statements; this might be silly &obvious, but you're sure they're set before you run the commands, yes? (Can't hurt to check the little things...)

Comment: @jhaagsma the values are set as they are a datatable - I spit out to csv exactly what was there as the code ran - what is posted is what I see. I think with Marc B editing my question - he helped me look at something in the MySqlAdapter generated insert command - there are 4 columns of data - I have 5 columns Id field being the first. I ran the code manually in workbench - it worked - so it looks like the MySQLAdapter is not generating the field value of Primary Key field for insert.   I have AddWithKey when I get the table, I need that. MsqlDA is disposed. Later I need to update / insert.

Comment: @MarcB I have posted all of the code for recreating the scenario - VB code, create tables code - example data .. one thing I noticed is if I create the InsertQuery to include the PK - it tells me that my binId value is null - but it is not (the original row version is because it is an Added Row - but the current is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WOW 2 days of hammering away and I finally found the answer. I am posting this here for the benefit of others who might be struggling with a similar issue.

In my scenario the datatable was bound to a binding source - which I filtered. I needed to get the filtered list only - so I cloned my table and then imported the filtered rows. I passed this new table to my save method.

My Save Method uses the MySqlDataAdapter to Fill a datatable [dt] with the table data. I then Merge this with my table that has the imported rows.

So that was my scenario the problem is in the SaveDataTable method caused by this line of code:

> Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
>
> mySDA.Fill(dt)

When I changed that line to this:

> Dim dt As DataTable = datasTable.Clone()
>
> mySDA.Fill(dt)

The code worked as it should have.
I can't explain why that worked and the other did not they are from the same table same query. but if I clone the original and fill it, then merge it back with original - it works. Perhaps someone reading has the answer to that and would not mind posting a comment.

I hope this helps someone else who is having a similar issue.

Working Code below:

```
Private Sub SaveDataTable(datasTable As DataTable, query As String)

        Using con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(DatabaseConnection)

            Using comm As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, con)

                comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text

                Using mySDA As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(comm)

                    Try

                        con.Open()

                        Dim dt As DataTable = datasTable.Clone()

                        mySDA.Fill(dt)

                        dt.Merge(datasTable, False)

                        mySDA.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = True

                        Dim cmdBuild As MySqlCommandBuilder =
                                        New MySqlCommandBuilder(mySDA)

                        cmdBuild.GetDeleteCommand()

                        cmdBuild.GetInsertCommand()

                        cmdBuild.GetUpdateCommand()

                        mySDA.Update(dt)

                        Success = True

                    Catch sqlError As MySqlException

                        Dim exErr As String = String.Format("MySQL Error:
                        {0}: {1}", sqlError.Number, sqlError.Message)
                        MessageBox.Show(exErr, "Error While Saving Table", 
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

                    Catch concurrencyError As DBConcurrencyException

                        MessageBox.Show(concurrencyError.Message.ToString(),
                       "Error While Saving Table", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                       MessageBoxIcon.Error)

                    Catch ex As Exception

                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error While
                        Saving Table", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error)

                    Finally

                        con.Close()

                    End Try

                End Using

            End Using

        End Using

End Sub
```